# Unable to connect to amazon athena from power bi desktop

Tags: amazon-athena, powerbi-desktop

Facing issue when trying to connect to AWS Athena from ODBC connection from simba athena from power bi desktop i have power BI Desktop in Windows EC2 instance. Getting the below error:

[image]

Please help to fix the issues since tried lot of ways for troubleshooting.